# How to keep the "Provider Connection String" separate from the EF (EDMX) metadata information?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, edmx

I would like to be able to handle the *actual* Connection String and the EF metadata connection string separately in the config (app.config, web.config) - the goal is to make the *actual* data-source more apparent.

I have complete control over creating the EF Context (yay IoC!), but don't want to hard-code any of the values. Preferably something like:

```
<add name="EfEntities"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/..;provider connection string=NO;.." />
<add name="EfEntities_Provider"
     connectionString="data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DB;user id=ME" />
```

It would also be acceptable, and possibly better, is the deployed configs had only the conglomerated EF connection string - as long as it was *built from separate properties* in the source configs. (But this level of config transformation escapes me.)

I'm fine living with the conglomerated EF "connection string" for the Designer / Updater - the EDMX is in a separate project from the usage in the target assemblies that are deployed.

Comment: The easiest way is to go away from edmx file and weird connection string. The main reason - [EF won't support it in ver. 7.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx), so you have a bunch of time to work out the transition, make the team familiar with the EF Fluent API.

Comment: @abatishchev I don't do "fluent ORM API". And I honestly wish for the way that I use EF (with an anemic model and all) that I could just use L2S or a variation. I believe firmly in model first - of much EDMX and EF barely handle usably past trivial situations - so basically it's about hammering a square peg in a round hole that is visibly too small at this point :< But at least I know.

Comment: @abatishchev Code First only wins without proper tooling - and it does exist, but isn't cheap for "the good stuff" - to do Model First and proper schema migrations. (Code First is arguably better for non-anemic and "OO" models, but again .. I am a [DATABASE] MODEL IS THE ONE TRUTH believer so such arguments are lost on me.)

Comment: I was using edmx for years without issues. But what can we do now?

Comment: @abatishchev Get a bigger hammer.

Comment: And as the article highlights, Bla First is an incorrect name. CF supposes you to decorate entities with attributes, I hate this. But now instead you can have clear POCOs and Fluent API using [DbConfiguration<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx). The main advantage is not to have a huge xml file you barely can merge in case of serious conflicts.

Comment: @abatishchev Thanks, I'll have to go back and look at "Code First" and my assumptions about it. Maybe  I can find a good method to generate it from the One Truth. But I am not going to write "fluent Code First" by hand or non-repeatable process - that was the wrongness (in my mind) with it to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my projects, I build the EF connection string myself in code and pass that to the Context object's constructor, like so:

```
void InitContext() {

    String actualConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["server123"].ConnectionString;

    String efConnectionString = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "metadata=res://*/..;provider connection string={0};.", actualConnectionString);

    _context = new MyEFContext( efConnectionString );
}
```

Comment: You can convert a code like this into a factory (`IFactory<DbContext>`, `Func<DbContext`, etc.) and make it injectable.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to "go" with the idea behind Dai's answer. There may be problems with it (eg. the password better not contain a quote); but it works here on tests and feels more "visible" in config transformations.

The code looks about like:

```cs
var edmxMetadata = GetConnectionStringSetting("EfEntities_Metadata");
var providerConnection = GetConnectionStringSetting("EfEntities_Provider");

var edmxCS = string.Format(@"{0};provider={1};provider connection string=""{2}""",
    edmxMetadata.ConnectionString,
    providerConnection.ProviderName,
    providerConnection.ConnectionString);

// (and by and by)
var context = new EfEntities(edmxCS);
```

Where:

```xml
<!-- just the metadata -->
<add name="EfEntities_Metadata"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/EfEntities.csdl|res://*/EfEntities.ssdl|res://*/EfEntities.msl"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<!-- just the provider connection string -->
<add name="EfEntities_Provider"
     connectionString="data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DB;user id=ME"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```